# Can't open dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

This is is going to sound like a very dumb question but how do you open dygraphs?
I go on the download page, download the dygraph-combined.js file but all that appears in my browser is a huge amount of letters and numbers that make no sense.

Usually I would just google "how to open .js file" but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 3):

The letters and numbers make up the [minified JavaScript](http://dygraphs.com/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js). You simply need to save it to a file on your local machine. If you're in Chrome, Right click > Save as... to download it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I've downloaded but can't open it...
what software do you use?

Comment: To open a JavaScript file? Whatever you use to edit code: Visual Studio, Eclipse, Sublime Text, Notepad...